# Function and if else in PHP

Tags: php, function, if-statement

i dont understand how the if statement works and the function is called, why i am getting "He has more strength", i know because the strength is greater, but what i am getting there, is it a boolean? can i dump it, it shows me NULL if i put this inside the if statement

edit:i have added the return.

```
<?php
class Ship
{
public $name;
public $strength = 0;

    public function doesGivenShipHaveMoreStrength($givenShip)
    {
         return $givenShip->strength > $this->strength;
    }
}

$myShip = new Ship();
$myShip->name = 'TIE Fighter';
$myShip->strength = 150;

$otherShip = new Ship();
$otherShip->name = 'Imperial Shuttle';
$otherShip->strength = 50;


if ($myShip->doesGivenShipHaveMoreStrength($otherShip)) {

 echo $otherShip->name.' He has more strength';

} else {
    echo $myShip->name.' She has more strength';

}


?>
```

Comment: Functions need return values, you're not returning anything so it gives false

Comment: [your code prints "She has more strength"](https://eval.in/767752)  , you have another code than you have posted

Comment: but why i am getting true or false, because of the "if"? how the function knows that because of ">" ?

Comment: off course! `>` is a comparison operator like `<, ==, ===, <=,>=`  when you write this in your program `(2 > 1)` it will be evaluated as `true` . so this code `return (2 > 1)` is the same as this code `return true`

Comment: I added some examples that might help you understand if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statements evaluates whatever inside it's braces `()` . if true or 1 the block or statement will be executed. your function returned a value , and that returned value is later evaluated by the `if` statement.  these are examples that might help you understand how if statements work. the same goes with almost every other programming language.

```
//example 1
if(true){
    // will be executed
}else{
    // will not executed
}
//example 2
if(false){
    // will not executed
}else{
    // will be executed
}

//example 3
if( 2 > 1){
    // will be executed
}else{
    // will not executed
}
//example 4
if(1){
    // will be executed
}else{
    // will not executed
}
//example 5
if(0){
    // will not executed
}else{
    // will be executed
}
//example 5
if(myFunction()){
    // will be executed
}else{
    // will not executed
}
function myFunction()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not written properly, it should be :

```
class Ship
{
public $name;
public $strength = 0;

    public function doesGivenShipHaveMoreStrength($givenShip)
    {
          return ($givenShip->strength > $this->strength);
    }
}
```

Then it will work as expected :) In your version, the function does return nothing, as a result when you use it, it evaluates to NULL, which is equivalent to false, and your test block fails !

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more point to the recently answers.

1. You must add `return`.
2. Even you add the `return`, you shall hit your block containing "`He has more strength`".

> Reason: you are comparing with `this->strength` which is `0` and your both objects have `strength` set to `150` & `50` accordingly. It's going to be always true. 
>   I would suggest to compare object level values if you are really want to achieve the same functionality.
>
> Revised Answer: You may need to adjust/fix your condition.

as per your code snippet at [here](https://eval.in/767758)

Your value of given ship shall be printed as `50` and current object value is `150` . your function is checking if 50 > 150? answer would be `false` and you shall hit your else.

Hope this helps

Comment: "$this->strength which is 0"  No, `$this->strength`  in the question means `$myShip->strength` which is 150

Comment: can you please double check by printing values of variables. 
$givenShip->strength  and $this->strength
Once you've values, you shall understand what I am talking about.

Comment: I doubled check sir. I'm correct it is 150 not 0 , take a look at [this live code](https://eval.in/767756)

Comment: Fix/Adjust your condition. You are getting right answer. 
Your given ship value is 50 and your calling object value is 150. The function shall return false and you shall hit "She has more strength"
return ($givenShip->strength > $this->strength);

Comment: yes thanks for your efforts.yes you are right `50 > 150` returns false .  but remember `$this->strength` is not 0 it is rather 150 because it is called on `$myShip` instance.